# Where to download elementary OS fonts for use in Ubuntu?

Tags: fonts

I am really fond of the fonts used in elementary OS. Is there a way to download them to use in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 7):

The good news is, you may find that many of the fonts used in elementary OS are already in Ubuntu! They are:

- [Raleway](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Raleway) (logotype font)
- [Droid Sans](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Droid+Sans) (window titles)
- [Open Sans](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans) (various)

Alternative, you can install the `elementary-fonts` package from the [elementary OS Stable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/stable).

Answer (score 3):

Fonts can be downloaded and installed manually:

1. Download fonts from [the elementary/fonts repository at GitHub](https://github.com/elementary/fonts). Navigate into the folders of the desired fonts.
2. Save the `*.ttf` files into `~/.fonts` (you might have to make hidden files and directories visible using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>).
3. Open terminal and type `sudo fc-cache -f -v` to rebuild font cache